# Pass two values to a function using two separate select drop downs

Tags: javascript, forms, select

I looked online for this and came close to a solution but nothing dealt with it directly.

I have two form select drop downs:

I want this many therapists -

```
<select name="calcXmultiple" onChange="javascript:calcTherapist(1, this.value)">
    <option selected="selected" value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
```

Working this many hours -

```
<select name="calcXmultiple" onChange="javascript:calcTherapist(1, this.value)">
    <option selected="selected" value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
```

I'm lost.

I want to send both of these values to a function.  I know how to send a single value to the function and it works fine.  How do I send two values?

Comment: Are you saying that when one select changes, you want to send the current value of both select elements to the function?

Comment: what I see are two of the same `<select>` but the second has an option `5`. Please post the correct markup so we can understand what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Give the two dropdown different names and different Ids

```
<select name="calcXmultiple1" id="calcXmultiple1" onChange="calcTherapist()">
 ...
</select>

<select name="calcXmultiple2" id="calcXmultiple2" onChange="calcTherapist()">
...
</select>
```

They have a common function

```
function calcTherapist()
{
   var calcXmultiple1 = document.getElementById('calcXmultiple1');
   var calcXmultiple2 = document.getElementById('calcXmultiple2');

   var therapist = calcXmultiple1.value; 
   var hours = calcXmultiple2.value;

   //doSomethingWith(therapist, hours);
}
```

Comment: codingbiz, that worked perfectly.  Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to get both values from within the function itself, instead of passing the values are parameters to the function.

If you give your `<select>` elements unique `id` attributes, you can do something like this:

```
var selectTherapists = document.getElementById("selectTherapists");
var selectHours = document.getElementById("selectHours");
var totalHours = selectTherapists.options[selectTherapists.selectedIndex].value * selectHours.options[selectHours.selectedIndex].value;
```